# JUnit5: Trouble Importing Assertions

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use JUnit5 to create some basic unit tests.  I go to my `Analyzer.java` class and get the popup for creating a test.  I hit `Create New Test`, setting Testing Library to JUnit5.  I check off a bunch of methods to generate test methods for and hit OK.

So now I have an `AnalyzerTest.java` file and at the top I have:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
```

Unfortunately, `Assertions` is red (this is in IntelliJ IDEA).  When I hover, it says "Cannot find symbol Assertions".  In a similar vein, I have:

```
 @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

before each test method and when I hover, I get "Cannot resolve symbol Test"

I simply want to create and then run some unit tests but obviously am doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added JUnit jupiter's library to your classpath?

Comment: @Mureinik Not sure, how would I do that / check?

Comment: In the project overview, scroll down to external libraries. If it's not there, that's probably your problem.

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry for being a noob, not sure where project overview is...thanks for the help!

Comment: The left-hand panel of IntelliJ

Answer (score 5):

## Gradle

Add the following dependency to your Gradle:

```
 testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1")
```

Under your dependencies.

```
    dependencies {
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1")
```

Comment: testCompile is obsolete. should be testImplementation now

Comment: Yes,This is a fairly old post.I will update the Code

Answer (score 2):

I don't know you are using or maven or gradle. But if you are using maven just add below dependecies in between your  tags. Let me know if you need more help regarding this. I have used older version below, you can check the latest version from https://mvnrepository.com and update the pom script.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use IntelliJ-IDEA, make sure your test file is in the **Test Sources roots**.
Because my project do not have the path `src/test/java`, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to add a test file, it added in `src/main/java`...

See [intellij support post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000167264-JUnit-5-cannot-resolve-symbol-Assertion-Test-class-not-in-TEST-scope-)

Answer (score 0):

## Maven

If using Maven, be sure to specify a `dependency` element inside the `dependencies` element.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use those Assertions outside of your test-related classes, in your regular app classes, drop the `<scope>test</scope>` element.

Note that as of 5.4.0 of JUnit, we can specify the new single Maven artifact of [`junitjupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) which in turn will supply 8 libraries to your project. Very convenient if you are writing only JUnit 5 tests (Jupiter test engine), and not “vintage” JUnit 4 tests or other test engines.

If using Gradle rather than Maven, see the [Answer by RileyManda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198870/642706).